# Changeing Maproute to a token other than {controller} routes to home page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my route config

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    name: "Default2",
        //    url: "{controller}/{action}/",
        //    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        //);
    }
```

If I type in

```
http://localhost:62378/thiscontrollerdoesnotexist
```

it give me this message

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /thiscontrollerdoesnotexist

but if I change my route to this

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controllerhithere}/{action}/{id}/",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            //routes.MapRoute(
            //    name: "Default2",
            //    url: "{controller}/{action}/",
            //    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            //);
        }
```

I changed the {controller} to {controllerhithere}. Now when I type in

```
http://localhost:62378/thiscontrollerdoesnotexist
```

It takes me to

```
http://localhost:62378/thiscontrollerdoesnotexist
```

but shows the home page?

How is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

This project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299531/Custom-routes-for-MVC-Application#premain7

Allows you to add the following line to your global.asax

```
RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Which will allow you to debug your routing and you can determine what matches and what is overriding.

[image]